# manually define page numbers in latex?

Tags: latex

I am editing a 100+ page document in latex, document class is "book".
The first few pages of the document have roman page numbers, the rest have arabic page numbers *starting with one*.
I.e. the document has page numbers i-iv, followed by pages 1-120.
However, want I want is the pages to be: vii-ix, followed by pages 1-120.
(reason: I am inserting some other PDF pages preceding the PDF ultimately generated by latex, and this obviously leads to all following page numbers beeing higher).

So how can I increase the roman page numbers to start from a higher number (but not increase the arabic page numbers at the samee time)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You don't need to use `\setcounter{page}{1}` when arabic numbers start. This happens automatically:

```
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\setcounter{page}{3}
a
\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
b
\end{document}
```

has page iii followed by page 1.

Answer (score 5):

use `\setcounter{page}{7}` after `\begin{document}` and if necessary `\setcounter{page}{1}` when the arabic page numbers start.

Answer (score 3):

Try using the [pdfpages package (CTAN)](http://www.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/pdfpages/), which allows you to insert PDF documents into your Latex document, and assign page numbers to them.  You need to use this with pdftex.

**Not very useful aside** — if you used [Context](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/), you'd be able to add page numbers to the PDF document you import, as well as other decoration.  But that is a big step away from Latex.

Comment: thanks, but I am already using the pdfpages package! my question, which is now solved (sorry I don't know how to mark the accepted answer) was more about how to change the pagenumbers following the included PDF.
Context looks very cool, I wish I had known about it earlier. Will consider using it for my next big document.

Answer (score 2):

The `book` (and report) classes define `\frontmatter`, `\mainmatter`, and `\backmatter`, to switch the page style and handling of sectioning. In particular `\frontmatter` switches the page numbers to roman, and `\mainmatter` to arabic.

To account for unprinted pages at the beginning, you still have to use `\setcounter{page}{7}`  before your front matter content.

Comment: This answer did not only solve my problems, but answered the question I was supposed to be asking instead of trying to find hacks to get the page numbering to work.